# Запись данных в базу и вывод их в <div>

Tags: ajax, modx

Не могу толком разобраться с Ajax. Есть у меня:

```
<div id="10">
<div  id="1">
 <input type="button" name="one">
</div> 
<div  id="1">
 <input type="button" name="two">
</div> 
<div  id="1">
 <input type="button" name="three">
</div> 
 </div> 
 <div id="2"></div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от того, какая кнопка нажималась, в базе записывалась строка с соответствующими кнопке данными, и... рядом в блок  выводились данные имеющиеся плюс данные, только что записанные в базе по нажатию кнопки. Желательно бы со сниппетом реализовать, не хочется что-то отдельные файлы клепать в папках сайта.

Comment: Покажите ваш код ajax и php файл и что там не получается сделать. Или вы совсем ничего не делали и хотите чтоб вам дали готовое решение?

Comment: Да не могу я понять вообще, как данные из блока в сниппет передать, из сниппета в базу - знаю, из базы в другой блок - не знаю. Был бы очень признателен, если бы хотя б на мысль навели. Код я и сам напишу, когда пойму что к чему.

Comment: https://www.codexworld.com/php-crud-operations-jquery-ajax-mysql/ - посмотрите этот урок. По нему можно понять как это всё должно работать

Comment: Я сделааааал)) Спасибо большое за ссылку, посмотрю обязательно. Я по Василию Наумкину сделал. Вечером скину результат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Содержимое ресурса:

```
[[!Ajax_price]]  

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.ajax_link_price').click(function() {

    var action = $(this).data('action');

    $.post(document.location.href, {action: action}, function(data) {

        $('#scart').html(data);
    })

    return false;
  })
})
</script>

<div class="card-body " > 
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary ajax_link_price" data-action="7">Добавить в блок</a>
 </div>

 <div  id="scart"  >
 Ещё ничего не добавлено
 </div>
```

Сниппет:

```
<?php 
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] != 'XMLHttpRequest') {return;}

if (empty($_POST['action'])) {return;}

// А если есть - работаем
   $user = $modx->getUser();
    $userid=$user->get('id');

  $sc_user= $modx->newObject('ShCar');
   $sc_user->set('user_id', $userid);  


$res = '';
switch ($_POST['action']) {
    case '7': 
        $sc_user->set('tariff_id', 7);  
        $sc_user->save(); 
        break;
    // А вот сюда потом добавлять новые методы
    case '8': 
        break;
    case '9': 
        break; 
}

 $full_sc_user_query= $modx->newQuery('ShCar'); 
 $full_sc_user_query->select(array( 
         'ShCar.id as id',
        'ShCar.name as name', 
));

  $full_sc_user_query->where(array(
    'ShCar.id' => $userid, 
));  

 $full_sc_user = $modx->getCollection('ShCar', $full_sc_user_query);  

 foreach ($full_sc_user as $tov_sc_user) { 

  $output .= ' <div>'.$tov_sc_user->get('id').' '.$tov_sc_user->get('name').'</div><br>';
   }

   $res = $output;

// Если у нас есть, что отдать на запрос - отдаем и прерываем работу парсера MODX
if (!empty($res)) {
    die($res);
}
```

Такое вот творчество у меня получилось) Конечно не без Наумкина. Ему отдельная благодарность)