# Кнопки удаления товаров из корзины методом Ajax

Tags: ajax, modx

Сделал корзину на сайте так.

[Запись данных в базу и вывод их в <div>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/895116/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2-div)

Но... Никак ума не дам, как добавить к каждому товару в корзине кнопку удаления. После загрузки корзины, кнопка срабатывает лишь один раз, потом корзина обновляется Ajax-ом и после этого реакции на нажатия ноль. Пробовал скрипт и вместе с корзиной подгружать (думал, что он при загрузке классы кнопок сканирует), и при загрузке страницы - ничего не выходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону смотреть, где моя ошибка?

Comment: Вы jQuery или ванильным JS пользуетесь?

Comment: jQuery подключается при загрузке страницы

Comment: Попробуйте написать такой обработчик клика: `$(document).on('click', '.selector', function(){})`. Если поможет в ответе напишу почему так.

Comment: Сделал. Спасибо огромное за подсказку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так.  Спасибо большое  Дмитрию Мирошниченко за хорошую подсказку. Скрипт необходимо выводить после блока с обновляющимися кнопками.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $("div#scart").on('click', 'a.ajax_link_price_rem', function() { 
    // Берем действие из атрибута data-remove ссылки
    var remove = $(this).data('remove'); 
    // Ajax запрос к текущей страницы (а на ней наш сниппет) методом post
    $.post(document.location.href, {remove: remove}, function(data) {
        // Выдаем ответ
        $('#scart').html(data);
    }) 
      return false;
});  

</script>
```